# Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method flutterToWatch on channel it.example.watch)

Tags: flutter

I am using [awesome_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_notifications) library, and to prevent, for example, *MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences)* it uses in AppDelegate:

```
SwiftAwesomeNotificationsPlugin.setPluginRegistrantCallback { registry in
          SwiftAwesomeNotificationsPlugin.register(
            with: registry.registrar(forPlugin: "io.flutter.plugins.awesomenotifications.AwesomeNotificationsPlugin")!)          
          FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin.register(
            with: registry.registrar(forPlugin: "io.flutter.plugins.sharedpreferences.SharedPreferencesPlugin")!)
      }
```

But I still have error with my custom channel:
*Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method flutterToWatch on channel it.example.watch)*
And I don't know how to register it in the background like awesome_notifications do it.

My channel:

```
private func initFlutterChannel() {
        if let controller = window?.rootViewController as? FlutterViewController {
            let channel = FlutterMethodChannel(
                name: "it.example.watch",
                binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)
            
            channel.setMethodCallHandler({ [weak self] (
                call: FlutterMethodCall,
                result: @escaping FlutterResult) -> Void in
                switch call.method {
                case "flutterToWatch":
                    guard let watchSession = self?.session, watchSession.isPaired, watchSession.isReachable, let methodData = call.arguments as? [String: Any], let method = methodData["method"], let data = methodData["data"] else {
                                            result(false)
                                            return
                                        }
                    
                    let watchData: [String: Any] = ["method": method, "data": data]
                    
                    // Pass the receiving message to Apple Watch
                    watchSession.sendMessage(watchData, replyHandler: nil, errorHandler: nil)
                    result(true)
                default:
                    result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: Close the app and execute flutter run command.

Answer (score 49):

Just close the app running on your Editor, and start your app to run again (dont hot restart / hot reload), stop your app and start it again!

Comment: This worked for me the error was MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method check on channel dev.fluttercommunity.plus/connectivity)

Answer (score 13):

I had this bug recently when changing few packages.

I just clear Flutter with `flutter clean`, delete pubspec.lock, and `Invalidate and Restart` Android Studio.
A last `flutter pub get` to restore packages and everything worked good.

Comment: Finaly, not sure that `Invalidate and Restard` is necessary, but it's not bad

Comment: You might also need to enable Developer Mode in your system settings. Run `start ms-settings:developers` to open settings.

Answer (score 6):

I've faced same issue here and error was in AppDelegate.swift
By putting in this line of code

```
GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
```

I solved this problem

Comment: thanks, I can't upvote this enough.

Answer (score 3):

I quote from https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/98473 which solved the problem for me:

> To summarize the actual solution: at the start of the entry point for any isolate that needs to use plugins (where you are presumably already calling WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()):

> For Flutter 2.11+ (currently master), call DartPluginRegistrant.ensureInitialized(), which will run the Dart plugin registration for all plugins that need it.
> For older versions of Flutter, manually call the registerWith of any plugin implementations you use that have Dart registration. For shared_preferences, see above for details.

Since the plan going forward is to require `DartPluginRegistrant.ensureInitialized()` in isolates, closing as fixed.

Comment: I tried DartPluginRegistrant.ensureInitialized(), but nothing changes, error still appears.
There is an issue about DartPluginRegistrant working https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/99883

Comment: What is your flutter version?

Comment: 2.12.0-4.1.pre version

Answer (score 3):

close the app and then just run.

```
flutter clean;
flutter pub get;
flutter run;
```

You'll get to go.

Answer (score 2):

I also faced the error-

```
Error: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method initialize on channel plugin.csdcorp.com/speech_to_text)
```

This page- [Github issue link](https://github.com/csdcorp/speech_to_text/issues/156) helped me.
I changed my plugin version in *pubspec.yaml* file and it worked for me.

[image: Edited code]

**Or**

you can use the command in terminal-

```
flutter pub outdated
flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
```

Answer (score 1):

i fixed that by run my flutter app again.

Answer (score 1):

for simple solution you can use try-catch block as bellow

```
List<CameraDescription> cameras = [];
    async {
      try {
        WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
        cameras = await availableCameras();
      } on MissingPluginException catch (e) {
        showDialog<void>(
          context: context,
          barrierDismissible: false,
          // user must tap button!
          builder: (BuildContext context) =>
              AlertDialog(
                title: const Text(
                    'Opps.. No Camera Found!'),
                content:
                const  SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: ListBody(
                    children: <Widget>[
                       Text(
                          'It seems your current device has no any camera attached'),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  TextButton(
                    child: const Text(
                        'Dismiss'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context)
                          .pop();
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
        );
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just stop you app and restart it again will solve the problem in most of the cases.

This happens because some native dependency requires an update and that only happens when you restart the application.

Answer (score -1):

If your reason for encountering this problem was because you downloaded google_font into you pub.yaml. Please restart the project from afresh, while your internet is on

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

if you are using   await window_manager package, make sure you wrarp ensureInitialized() method inside a function that has approved it is a wondows platform, otheriwise if you call that method before checking is a windows platform, your app will crash and show black screen.
do it like in the code below

```
if (Platform.isWindows) {
    await windowManager.ensureInitialized();
    WindowManager.instance
        .setMinimumSize(Size(Get.width / 1.2, Get.height / 1.2));
  }
```

REMEMBER TO THANK ME IF IT HELPS YOU!

Answer (score -3):

this can be solved by putting some changes in build.gradle under build types

```
proguardFiles(
    getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
    "proguard-rules.pro"
)A
```

reference: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#kts