# Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method launch on channel plugins.flutter.io/url_launcher_android)

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to send a whatsapp message from my flutter app but I get the error: Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method launch on channel plugins.flutter.io/url_launcher_android).
Everything I found through my research did not work with me. please help me please.

```
    void openWhatsapp(
    {required BuildContext context,
      required String text,
      required String number}) async {
    var whatsapp = number; //+92xx enter like this
    var whatsappURlAndroid =
      "whatsapp://send?phone=" + whatsapp + "&text=$text";
    var whatsappURLIos = "https://wa.me/$whatsapp?text=${Uri.tryParse(text)}";
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
    // for iOS phone only
    if (await canLaunchUrl(Uri.parse(whatsappURLIos))) {
      await launchUrl(Uri.parse(
        whatsappURLIos,
      ));
    } else {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          const SnackBar(content: Text("Whatsapp not installed")));
    }
    } else {
    // android , web
    if (await canLaunchUrl(Uri.parse(whatsappURlAndroid))) {
      await launchUrl(Uri.parse(whatsappURlAndroid));
    } else {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          const SnackBar(content: Text("Whatsapp not installed")));
    }
    }
    }
```

I tried:

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71646547/unhandled-exception-missingpluginexceptionno-implementation-found-for-method-f)

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63312503/i-want-to-launch-whatsapp-application-from-my-flutter-application)

...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened to me one time and it has two causes:

- you didn't follow the [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) package's specific necessary configuration for your target devices.
- you didn't delete the build folder and run your app again, first run:

  ```
  flutter clean
  flutter pub get
  ```

  And re-run your app in the emulator/device ( Not hot restart, you need to stop your app, and run it again)

Hope this helps!